# Referring same IP with different canonical or alias name in /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, ip, alias, ip-address, cname

Would like to access my application - instead of from http://foomachine.mydomain.org:8080 to 
http://someFancynewCanonicalName.mydomain.org:8080

Tried with editing `/etc/hosts` considering it is in format `IP CNAME Alias` by duplicating entry referring to same IP like below. But I couldn't load on new one. Am I missing anything?

```
192.168.1.10    foomachine.mydomain.org       foo
192.168.1.10    someFancynewCanonicalName.mydomain.org       someNewAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, sorry you are right: 
meaning: 
to make the web server reply to new alias , this alias should be declared as server name in the virtual host:

---

server {
  listen 80 default_server; 
  foomachine.mydomain.org someFancynewCanonicalName.mydomain.org; 
...
}

Comment: Hello, Irsute. Please, consider providing more information about your answer instead of linking to external source.

Comment: Hi @Irsute, sorry I don't follow - is it related to `hosts` file?

Comment: Hi @vinWin, <br/>
Just asking :<br/>
If you try to reach http://someFancynewCanonicalName.mydomain.org:8080 instead of foomachine.mydomain.org:8080 <br/>
the alias should first appear on yout web server configuration first <br/>
What kind of web server is behind foomachine.mydomain.org: <br/>
apache / nginx / cherrypy /... ?

Comment: Not looking anything from enabling things from web server or app deployment. Trying to figure out way of aliasing with new name and accessing that with new framed url. Not sure `nslookup` itself is expected to fail per implementation when one goes for fetching full host name or canonical name with `hostname` on Linux.  As part of one of change I am looking at this option if available which enables this functionality without controlling anything from config level like at httpd.conf etc, but just from /etc/hosts file

Comment: @vinWin, maybe you can add the new aliases on the same line of the frist register: <br/>
`code` 192.168.1.10 foomachine.mydomain.org foo someFancyCN.domain.net somaeAlias

Comment: It's doesn't look to changing much, may be per syntax highlighted in OP. Was thinking duplicating entry with appropriate changes I thought is the option. Need to explore more on creating that new alias name which I am looking at